# How to check Google SMTP current remaining quota?

Tags: google-api, gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-developers-console

I am using google smtp to send a lot of mails, but if I send too much mails it will return quota error.

So I want to check my quota anytimes.

But I didn't find any about this.

Is there any way like API to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to check your quota via an api.   You can check google developer console for your project manually but this is an estimate at the very best.

My advice is to keep a running total of the requests you are sending and try to space them out so that you don't hit any of the quotas.

Once you hit a quota error makes sure you stop and take a break for a little while, possibly implementing exponential backoff, but this depends upon which quota you are hitting.